# Is it possible to use Fey step to bypass locks?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, teleportation

In D&D 4e Eladrin get an ability called fey step which allows them to teleport 5 squares per encounter. Would an Eladrin be able to peek through a keyhole and bypass a door by teleporting?

Comment: Your Eladrin should carry a [manual drill](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=manual+drill).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Yes, *if* they can actually see through the keyhole.

From the RC, p214:

> **Line of Sight:** The user of the teleportation power must have line of sight to the destination space.
>
> **No Line of Effect Required:** Neither the user of the teleportation power nor the target needs line of effect to the destination space.

So as long as you can see the spot you're trying to teleport to, you can teleport there.

Whether you can actually see through the keyhole is a separate question. If you check the keyholes on most doors around you, I would bet that you can't use them to look into the area on the other side of the door. Generally the higher quality the lock, the less likely it is that you'll be able to see through it.

Comment: Given the relatively low probability of being able to see through a keyhole on any non-ancient door, it's better/more reliable to use the undercut for this, really. (You can get security undercut barriers, but they're not common door fixtures)

Comment: @Shalvenay Fortunately most doors encountered by a 4e adventurer are probably ancient

Comment: Any door worth locking enough to matter should be warded against teleportation by making sure you can't see past/through/under the door.  We can't use earth standards to imagine how doors and locks would look.  Teleportation is a normal thing that requires simple countermeasures.  The party should be forced to make their own hole through the door to see through (assuming that they can and there aren't traps against this).